How to update a Kedro pipeline instead of replacing it?
I have a dataset which I have to increment every run, but it is instead replacing it.
The catalog is generalized, except for the result.csv, which is a concatenated file of all the other files generated by the pipelines.
"{namespace}.{dataset_name}@csv":
  type: pandas.CSVDataset
  filepath: data/01_raw/{namespace}/{dataset_name}.csv
  versioned: True

"{namespace}.result":
  type: pandas.CSVDataset 
  filepath: data/01_raw/{namespace}/result.csv

In the nodes.py file, I'm using a simple concatenation function, besides the scrapers and results processors.
def concatenate_csvs(*dataframes):
    concatenated_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
    return concatenated_df

and on the pipelines, I'm just calling all the outputs of the previous pipelines. Base pipe:
def create_pipeline(**kwargs):
  
    pipe_the_hacker_news = pipeline(
        [
            node(
                func=get_links,
                inputs=["params:the_hacker_news"],
                outputs="the_hacker_news_links",
                name="the_hacker_news_links_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=scraper_the_hacker_news,
                inputs="the_hacker_news_links",
                outputs="the_hacker_news@csv",
                name="the_hacker_news_scraper_node",
            )
        ],
        namespace="cybersecurity_news"
    )        

Concatenated:
    pipe_concat = pipeline(
        [
            node(
                func=concatenate_csvs,
                inputs=[
                    "the_hacker_news@csv",
                    "tech_republic@csv",
                    "thecyberexpress_news@csv",
                    "welivesecurity_news@csv",
                    "davinciforensics_news@csv",
                    "varutra_news@csv",
                    "attcybersecurity_news@csv",
                    "mcafee_news@csv",
                    "nist_news@csv",
                    "avast_news@csv",
                    "amazon_news@csv",
                    "qualys_news@csv",
                    "veracode_news@csv",
                    "gbhackers_news@csv",
                    "hackingarticles_news@csv",
                    "sentinelone_news@csv",
                    "securityintelligence_news@csv",
                    "tripwire_news@csv",
                    "securelist_news@csv",
                    "grahamcluley_news@csv",
                    "infosecurity_news@csv",
                    "olukaii_news@csv",
                    "cyble_news@csv",
                    "bleepingcomputer_news@csv",
                    "threatinsight_news@csv",
                    "zonealarm_news@csv"],
                outputs="result",
                name="concatenate_csvs_node",
            ),
        ],
        namespace="cybersecurity_news"
    )


How can I make it so my file instead of getting replaced, gets incremented for each run, avoiding duplicates?
I already tried using:
  save_args:
    mode: a

and nothing happened, and tried changing it directly on the nodes.py:
def concatenate_csvs(*dataframes):
    concatenated_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
    
    file_path = "/path/cybersecurity_news/result.csv"
    existing_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    concatenated_df = pd.concat([existing_df, concatenated_df], ignore_index=True)
    concatenated_df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
    return concatenated_df

but it was only using the previous version, and not updating it.

Hi, kedro is a very outdated framework. I would suggest to use dagster.

If you haven't tried already, give this a read. A combination of Incremental dataset and "append" file mode might help. Try -

Feed the inputs as Incremental datasets of CSVDataset, which only process the new incoming file.
The subsequent node will open an existing CSV file and append (append mode) the new data into it.

